# My comment are running out of comment box

Tags: php, html, css

In my web i allow user to post comment with there name and picture. I have notice one issue that when some one post bigger picture in comment using html code it run out of comment box. so all i want is thing should stay inside a comment box. not matter how big picture they post. i have posted all detail below kindly help thanks :|

[image]

My html

```
<div class="mycomment">
        <div id="postpic">
            <img id="profile_pic" width="50px" height="150px" src="image/user/1.gif" class="">
        </div>
        <div class="mycommentpost">                     
            <a class="postername" href="profile.php?userID=1">Deepak Kumar: </a><br>
            <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/789295022/-font-b-Easter-b-font-day-font-b-Bunny-b-font-ears.jpg" width="650" height="350" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.mycomment {
font-weight: normal;
color: #000000;
border: 2px solid #DEDEDE;
letter-spacing: 1pt;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
float: left;
width: 550px;
margin: 20px 0;
}

#postpic {
float: left;
width: 70px;
}

.mycommentpost {
font-weight: normal;
color: #000000;
letter-spacing: 1pt;
width: 480px;
float: right;
}

.postername {
color: #580000;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1em;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment here is just a picture:

```
<img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/789295022/-font-b-Easter-b-font-day-font-b-Bunny-b-font-ears.jpg" width="650" height="350" alt="">
```

**Solved :** By adding this ->

```
.mycommentpost > img{
    max-height: XXXpx !important;
    max-width: XXXpx !important;
}
```

Comment: Reduce the image width and height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your CSS

```
.mycommentpost > img{
    max-height: XXXpx !important;
    max-width: XXXpx !important;
}
```

This way you will limit the max sizes of added images..

Comment: I would like to ask additional question can i set div max-height same way as we did img because some user post div to :)

Comment: At first place I don't recommend you to allow users to post HTML tags for security reasons.. How ever if your code is secured you can use the same CSS idea - .mycommentpost > div (this will go to all DIV elements inside your mycommentpost class). But if user set style settings inside his elements your css code may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="mycomment">
    <div id="postpic">
        <img id="profile_pic" width="50px" height="150px" src="image/user/1.gif" class="">
    </div>
    <div class="mycommentpost">                     
        <a class="postername" href="profile.php?userID=1">Deepak Kumar: </a><br>
        <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/789295022/-font-b-Easter-b-font-day-font-b-Bunny-b-font-ears.jpg" width="650" height="350" alt="">
    </div>
```

```
.mycommentpost {
font-weight: normal;
color: #000000;
letter-spacing: 1pt;
width: 480px;
float: left;
}
.mycommentpost img{
 width :450px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no matter what size of image they upload using this css set the image to default size in your mycommentpost div.

```
> .mycommentpost img{
>      border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
>     padding: 10px;
>     width: 130px; }
```